# What does mean the word "Way" at the beginning of sentences?

Tags: meaning

What does mean the word "Way" at the beginning of the sentence "Way to do something".

And is it a noun or an adverb?

For example:

Way to work that diaper.

Way to explain that joke.

Way to bring it around.

Way to make a play for the middle class.

Way to kill the spirit!

Way to make a plan and stick to it.

Comment: It's a synonym for **method, procedure, technique**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In US English (and *perhaps* other types of English, I'm not sure), this is really an idiomatic expression.

I think it must be short for something like:

"[That was an excellent] way to ... [do some activity]!"

It can be used either as sincere praise:

> "Way to use your athletic skills!"

or sarcastically, as a real reprimand:

> "Way to make us all look like idiots."

or jestingly, as your example:

> "Way to kill the spirit!"